# Does the iPhone 7 have true tone display?

Tags: iphone

I got the iPhone 7, and I can't seem to find the true tone display setting. Is it still iPad Pro 9.7" exclusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True Tone was not implemented in the iPhone 7 or iPhone 7 Plus' display. There is, however, a wider color gamut (P3) and "improved color management".

Comment: Thanks. How do you make sure an iPhone is legit? I didn't buy it from apple. I am asking, since when I tried to reset it, it gave a yellow screen but now it's fixed.

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question if you have essentially-unrelated other issues or questions.